# Can´t get 8-bit shift register working (CD4014BE)

Tags: arduino, pic, shift-register

I can't seem to get my 8-bit shift register working. It's the CD4014BE.
The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4021b.pdf).
I've confirmed that the clock (pin 2) is ticking and the input (pin 4) is continuously switching between 0 and 1 on every clockcycle. I've tried multiple different setups, swapped components, but nothing works.

My code:

```
int clockPin = 2;
int dataPin = 4;

void setup() {
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(dataPin, HIGH);
  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
  delay(400);
  digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
  delay(400);

  digitalWrite(dataPin, LOW);
  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
  delay(400);
  digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
  delay(400);
}
```

[image: My setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LED is connected to an input. It needs to be connected to an output to work.

All the Px pins are inputs and should be connected to 0V or 5V. You can take outputs from pins 2, 12 or 3. Your LED should have a series resistor of a few hundred ohms, but this chip is wimpy enough it won't likely hurt anything.

Comment: Ah I see.. I thought this IC had parallel output and serial input, but that's another one, too bad.. Thanks.